# Google Analytics metrics for my Google Play application

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play

There is Google Analytics that I can use to find metrics about the the users come to my web sites. Is there a tool that would implement similar behavior with my Google Play applications?

Example: I have a [barcode to price comparison application in Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sanapeli.hintavertailu) (only available in Finland). Can I find out if the users ending up on that page come from Google search, Google Play search, Google Play suggestions, some web forum or even this question? Are the users mobile or desktop users? Do they download the application or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can answer many, but not all, of these questions using the [Google Play / Google Analytics Integration that was announced recently](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2013/10/google-play-integration.html).

Note that you will not be able to see which users came from a Google Play search, they will show up as having the source (direct).

Moreover, in contrast to how things work with web tracking, you will need to manually tag your links using Google Analytics 'utm' campaign parameters, or use auto-tagging if you are running AdWords ads, in order for source, campaign, keyword, info etc. to be populated in the new Google Play referral flow report.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing awales's answer and doing some investigation myself, I found Google Analytics Q&A: [Link Google Analytics and Google Play](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2956981)

So, you can set up your existing Google Analytics account to also reach Google Play applications. You have to enable the feature in Google Analytics *Admin* view, by toggling *Get Google Play Developer Console data* on and finally selecting the GP apps to follow.

It seems that you must have Google Analytics and Google Play developer account under the same Google user account to be able to do the linking.